# passing parameters to nested functions

Tags: javascript

This is my code:

```
var Placemat = function(id,id2) {
    this.hand = document.getElementById(id);
    this.bucket = "";
    this.bucketspace = document.getElementById(id2);
    this.bucketvalue = 0;
    var that = this;
    this.deal = function(id) {
        shuffle();
        var card1 = deck.shift();
        var card2 = deck.shift();
        this.hand.innerHTML = card1 + ", " + card2;
    };
    this.hit = function(id2) {
        var card3 = deck.shift();
        this.bucket = this.bucket + deck.shift();
        this.bucketspace.innerHTML = this.bucket; 
    };
};
```

Is this the proper way to pass parameters to a nested function? This `id` and `id2` in `this.deal()` and `this.hit()` are from `Placemat()`.

Comment: I don't see what the arguments are for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, if you want to use the values that were sent to `Placemat()`, you need to reference them in the `deal()` and `hit()` functions. Not list them as parameters to those functions.

```
 // removed---------v
this.deal = function() {
    alert( id );  // <---- do something with the original argument
    shuffle();
    var card1 = deck.shift();
    var card2 = deck.shift();
    this.hand.innerHTML = card1 + ", " + card2;
};

 // removed--------v
this.hit = function() {
    alert( id2 );  // <---- do something with the original argument
    var card3 = deck.shift();
    this.bucket = this.bucket + deck.shift();
    this.bucketspace.innerHTML = this.bucket; 
};
```

Remember, the *parameter* is just an identifier for whatever may be passed to the function. The *argument* is what was actually passed.

You can reference the *argument* via the *parameter* you defined. So to have your functions reference those arguments sent to `Placemat()`, you can do so via the `id` and `id2` parameters.

But if those nested functions define their own `id` or `id2` parameter, then *that* is what will be referenced in those functions. You will have effectively *shadowed* the parameters in the outer function.

Answer (score 1):

No. In fact, what are you passing the id's in the first place? You don't use them in the functions.

The way you are doing it, you are creating two functions (`hit` and `deal`) which expect one argument each. Those arguments just happen to be named the same as the arguments to your outer function.